# Download and install a specific version of package in RHEL

Tags: linux, yum, rhel7

I want to install a specific verison of `util-linux` package, I am using RHEL7 and by default a `util-linux-2.23.2` is installed but this version do not support `lsblk -J` command(to print devices in JSON format).
Using command `yum list --showduplicate util-linux` shows a list of available version but all are `2.23.x` version.

Is there any way to install a package with own version choice? I want to install a `util-linux 2.23.1`

Comment: choice? ... May be ? .... Please update your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67835181/edit to show required version.

Answer (score 0):

I think better you use pkgs.org and select specific packages
If you need dependency you can find there